# regex; match tag with specific attributes

Tags: html, regex

I am aware regex is not recommended for parsing html. I have this tag, named *tag* and *tag* has many possible attributes and it has these 3 required attributes, their names *attr*, *bttr*, *cttr* are **known**. These attributes are assigned certain values that are not known. I need a regex, that matches these examples:

```
<tag attr="0" bttr="0" cttr="0" />
<tag attr="0" cttr="0" bttr="0" />
<tag bttr="0" attr="0" cttr="0" />
<tag bttr="0" cttr="0" attr="0" />
<tag cttr="0" attr="0" bttr="0" />
<tag cttr="0" bttr="0" attr="0" />
```

and there could possibly be other attributes, but not necessarily, for example:

```
<tag attr="0" cttr="0" bttr="0" dar-vienas="0" />
<tag bttr="0" cttr="0" dar-vienas="0" attr="0" />
<tag attr="0" dar-vienas="0" cttr="0" irdar-vienas="0" bttr="0" />
```

all these have to match. And this one must not match

```
<tag attr="0" dar-vienas="0" bttr="0" irdar-vienas="0" />
```

it is missing *cttr* attribute, cannot match. Alright, what's the regex? So far all my attempts have failed...

Comment: You said it all when you mentioned that regex is not suitable for parsing HTML.  You should use a DOM parser instead and check the attributes using code.

Comment: That is no answer. I have to use regex for some mysterious reason, God knows why... maybe it is my assignment. The reason does not really matter

Comment: You should at least provide what you've tried. It also is a terrible assignment. Like teaching someone how to execute SQL without prepared statements, then showing them prepared statements after.

Answer (score 0):

We can try using lookaheads which assert that each of the `attr`, `bttr`, and `cttr` attributes occurs inside the `<tag>`:

```
<tag (?=((?!\/>).)*\battr="0")(?=((?!\/>).)*\bbttr="0")(?=((?!\/>).)*\bcttr="0").*?\/>
```

### Demo

For an explanation, there are three lookaheads in the above pattern, one for each attribute.  Here is how the first one works:

```
(?=              lookahead
    ((?!\/>).)*  and consume any input, without passing the end of the <tag>,
    \battr="0"   then assert that we can find attribute 'attr' inside the tag
)
```

Note that you spoke correctly when you said that regex should not be used for parsing HTML; it shouldn't be.  Instead, the best solution here would probably be to use some sort of DOM parser.

Comment: well, demo says it took too long to finish. And I have tried this code on my machine as well, does not finish. Seems like it got caught up in a loop or smth

Comment: @user3600124 If I had known you were working on a HackerRank question, I would not have answered.  _Don't_ use regex in this case, use a DOM parser.